# PHP increase memory limit with environmental variable?

Tags: php

A PHP script I am running (that is `+x`) is running out of memory:

```
Williams-MacBook-Air:pmtsystem williamentriken$ phpcpd --exclude core/ .
phpcpd 2.0.1 by Sebastian Bergmann.


Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes)     in phar:///usr/local/bin/phpcpd/src/Detector/Strategy/Default.php on line 78
```

Is it possible to increase the memory for just running this one instance of `phpcpd`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes there is, try this:

```
php -d memory_limit=256M phpcpd --exclude core/ .
```

This will allocate 256Mb instead of your current 128Mb limit